# Generate json layout using list

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build JSON layout. I am reading all these records from input file. There could be multiple records with the same key(Id) in the file.

***Sample Input File:***

```
Id,LineNo,Amt,ReceivedDt,FromDt,ToDate,regionId
123545,1,1000.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123545,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123545,3,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123546,1,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA13
123546,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA13
```

My logic is to read records from file in dictionary format and keep appending it
in the list until the same key(Id) matches. If the keys stops matching, delete the list and append the new key and then compare the records with this new key. In between, the results needs to be stored so that I don't lose previously processed records. (This is what I am not able to figure it out).

***Code :***

```
import json,csv

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = []
    key =1
    for row in inputfile :

        if len(output)==0:
            output.append(row)

        elif len(output)>0:
            if row['Id']==key:
                output.append(row)

            else:
                del output[:]
                output.append(row)
        key=row['Id']
        data = json.dumps({"data":output}, indent=4)

print(data)
```

***Output :***
Only last 2 rows are coming as the first group is getting deleted.
Please suggest how to store those rows.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Desired output :***

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "1000.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "3",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import csv
import json
import itertools
import operator

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = [{'data': list(rows)} 
        for id_, rows in itertools.groupby(cf, key=operator.itemgetter('Id'))]
data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite as succinct and elegant as using `itertools.groupby`, here's one way it could which involves manually keeping track of group of data with the same `Id`:

```
import csv
import json

with open('Test.csv') as f:
    output = []
    data = []
    key = None

    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        if row['Id'] == key:
            data.append(row)
        else:
            if data:
                output.append({"data": data})
                data = []
            data.append(row)
            key = row['Id']

    if data:  # A final group?
        output.append({"data": data})

print('output:\n', json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
output:
 [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Id": "123545",
                "LineNo": "1",
                "Amt": "1000.00",
                "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "regionId": "WA12"
            },
            {
                "Id": "123545",
                "LineNo": "2",
                "Amt": "200.00",
                "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "regionId": "WA12"
            },
            {
                "Id": "123545",
                "LineNo": "3",
                "Amt": "200.00",
                "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "regionId": "WA12"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Id": "123546",
                "LineNo": "1",
                "Amt": "200.00",
                "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "regionId": "WA13"
            },
            {
                "Id": "123546",
                "LineNo": "2",
                "Amt": "200.00",
                "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
                "regionId": "WA13"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```